# Leaflet: Change icon inside a function

Tags: leaflet, icon, function

I have a custom function that pulls the markers from a json file called markers.json :

```
var markers = {
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "AITokarServer",
      "coords": [
        {
          "x": -1210.0,
          "y": -1770.0
        },
     },
    {
      "name": "AIShigiServer",
      "coords": [
        {
          "x": -1310.0,
          "y": -1570.0
        },
     }
}
```

This is the function:

```
  function showResourcesByName(resName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
            var name = markers.resources[i].name;

            if (name == resName) {
                var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
                var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

                L.marker([y, x], {icon: bor}).addTo(map).bindPopup(name);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Using the Function to show markers on map:

```
  showResourcesByName("AIBorServer");
```

How can I change the icons of each "name" field after I call them on the function?

Something like:

```
showResourcesByName("AIBorServer"),(BorIconHere);
showResourcesByName("AIShigiServer"),(ShigiIconHere);
```

Comment: Do you want to change icons *after* you already put them on the map, or while you do it?

Comment: What's the difference? If I change them after or while I do it?  I want to have each group of markers with its own icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a few icons:

```
var BorIconHere = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/6_df.png',
        iconSize: [17, 30]
    }
});
var ShigiIconHere = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
      iconUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/4_lmb.png',
      iconSize: [17, 30]
  }
})
```

Add a second parameter `resIcon` to your `showResourcesByName` function that takes an icon:

```
function showResourcesByName(resName, resIcon) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
          var name = markers.resources[i].name;

          if (name == resName) {
              var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
              var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

              // use the "resIcon" parameter from the function call here, the 'new' keyword is required here
              L.marker([y, x], {icon: new resIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(name);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

And then add markers with custom icons like this:

```
showResourcesByName("AIBorServer", BorIconHere);
showResourcesByName("AIShigiServer", ShigiIconHere);
```

Working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/LVzmRcsVZ79wZ78E5yBd?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you so much!  
Now I will try to make it work with leaflet cluster marker. To group all those markers together when the zoom is far.